# find the consecutive values in impala

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have a data set below with ID, Date and Value. I want to flag the ID where three consecutive days has value 0.

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/10/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 8/11/2021 | 0 |
| 1 | 8/12/2021 | 0 |
| 1 | 8/13/2021 | 0 |
| 1 | 8/14/2021 | 5 |
| 2 | 8/10/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 8/11/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 8/12/2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 8/13/2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 8/14/2021 | 6 |
| 3 | 8/10/2021 | 3 |
| 3 | 8/11/2021 | 4 |
| 3 | 8/12/2021 | 0 |
| 3 | 8/13/2021 | 0 |
| 3 | 8/14/2021 | 0 |

output

| id | date | value | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/10/2021 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 8/11/2021 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | 8/12/2021 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | 8/13/2021 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | 8/14/2021 | 5 | Y |
| 2 | 8/10/2021 | 2 | N |
| 2 | 8/11/2021 | 3 | N |
| 2 | 8/12/2021 | 0 | N |
| 2 | 8/13/2021 | 0 | N |
| 2 | 8/14/2021 | 6 | N |
| 3 | 8/10/2021 | 3 | Y |
| 3 | 8/11/2021 | 4 | Y |
| 3 | 8/12/2021 | 0 | Y |
| 3 | 8/13/2021 | 0 | Y |
| 3 | 8/14/2021 | 0 | Y |

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a free code/script writing service but a question and answer site for specific programming-related issues.
Hence you have to try it on your own first, and when stuck, come back here, edit your question and provide a minimal reproducible example of your coding attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please take the tour and read How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window count() function you can count 0's in the frame [current row, 2 following] (ordered by date) - three consecutive rows frame calculated for each row:

`count(case when value=0 then 1 else null end) over(partition by id order by date_ rows between current row and 2 following ) cnt`.

If count happens to equal 3 then it means 3 consecutive 0's found, case expression produces `Y` for each row with cnt=3 : `case when cnt=3 then 'Y' else 'N' end`.

To propagate 'Y' flag to the whole id group use `max(...) over (partition by id)`

Demo with your data example (tested on Hive):

```
with mydata as (--Data example, dates converted to sortable format yyyy-MM-dd
select 1 id,'2021-08-10' date_, 1 value union all
select 1,'2021-08-11',0 union all
select 1,'2021-08-12',0 union all
select 1,'2021-08-13',0 union all
select 1,'2021-08-14',5 union all
select 2,'2021-08-10',2 union all
select 2,'2021-08-11',3 union all
select 2,'2021-08-12',0 union all
select 2,'2021-08-13',0 union all
select 2,'2021-08-14',6 union all
select 3,'2021-08-10',3 union all
select 3,'2021-08-11',4 union all
select 3,'2021-08-12',0 union all
select 3,'2021-08-13',0 union all
select 3,'2021-08-14',0
) --End of data example, use your table instead of this CTE

select id, date_, value, 
       max(case when cnt=3 then 'Y' else 'N' end) over (partition by id) flag
from
(
select id, date_, value, 
 count(case when value=0 then 1 else null end) over(partition by id order by date_ rows between current row and 2 following ) cnt
from mydata
)s
  order by id, date_  --remove ordering if not necessary
                      --added it to get result in the same order
```

Result:

```
id  date_       value   flag    
1   2021-08-10  1       Y
1   2021-08-11  0       Y
1   2021-08-12  0       Y
1   2021-08-13  0       Y
1   2021-08-14  5       Y
2   2021-08-10  2       N
2   2021-08-11  3       N
2   2021-08-12  0       N
2   2021-08-13  0       N
2   2021-08-14  6       N
3   2021-08-10  3       Y
3   2021-08-11  4       Y
3   2021-08-12  0       Y
3   2021-08-13  0       Y
3   2021-08-14  0       Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the ids by comparing `lag()`s.  Then spread the value across all rows.  The following gets the flag on the third `0`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value = 0 and prev_value_date_2 = prev_date_2
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as flag_on_row
from (select t.*,
             lag(date, 2) over (partition by value, id order by date) as prev_value_date_2,
             lag(date, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

The above logic uses `lag()` so it is easy to extend to longer streaks of `0`s.  The "2" is looking two rows behind, so if the lagged values are the same, then there are three rows in a row with the same value.

And to spread the value:

```
select t.*, max(flag_on_row) over (partition by id) as flag
from (select t.*,
             (case when value = 0 and prev_value_date_2 = prev_date_2
                   then 'Y' else 'N'
              end) as flag_on_row
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date, 2) over (partition by value, id order by date) as prev_value_date_2,
                   lag(date, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date_2
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want the flag to be Y if the value is 0 on three consecutive days. Where are we mentioning the 3 days.